# "derivative" is to "derive" as "primitive function" is to "?"

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

Basically, what is the opposite verb of "derive", i.e. "to take the primitive function of"?

(Context: I'm trying to make wolframAlpha take the primitive of a function, but I can't get formulation correct.)

Comment: 'Derive' means 'work out the derived function corresponding to a primitive'. Work out f'(x) given f(x). If you want the reverse process, it's known as integration. But you can't 'take the primitive of a function'; the one you start with **is** the primitive.

Comment: Is "integrate" the word I'm looking for then? Because I indeed need a word for the reversed process, that is, work out f(x) given f'(x).

Comment: Yep, looks like "integrate" is the one, Wolfram understood it. Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes. I won't post an answer, because the term is given at [Differentiate and Integrate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171018/differentiate-and-integrate). The opposite process to 'integrate' is not termed 'derive' but 'differentiate'.

Comment: Ah. Should I delete my question then?

Comment: It's not a poor question, and the other was not easy to find from where you started. I'd leave it. It does the site no harm. It's the questions like "How duu yuu spel 'plesent'?" or  "Is it 'I am here' or 'I are here'?" that  lose the site credibility.

Comment: Indeed, I would say that *integrate* is not an inversion of *derive*. B is derived from A; A is ... of B. Something to do with *precursor* would do there.

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Answer (score 2):

In calculus, I usually think of "integrate" as the verb for the opposite of the finding the derivative.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) "The process of solving for antiderivatives is called **antidifferentiation** (or **indefinite integration**) and its opposite operation is called **differentiation**, which is the process of finding a derivative" (*emphasis added*).

I usually think of the verb *derive* in mathematics in the context of formal proofs and abstract algebra.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding your answer to be completing the poster's fill-in-the-blank comparison with "_derivative_ is to _derive_ as _primitive function_ is to _integrate_"? If not, what word **does** go in the spot where I've inserted _integrate_?

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, but with the qualification that I'm not convinced the verb "derive" (which is better paired with the result-noun "[derivation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derivation.html)") is the best word for its position in the analogy.